# How can I load only certain images on certain screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I regards to responsive design, if I have a set of large background images that fade between each other on large screen sizes and have them hidden on smaller screen sizes do they still load on the smaller screen sizes? I don't want to use unnecessary bandwidth if the images aren't going to show. It seems that they do not load on my computer, but it is difficult for me to test for every possible setup. If they do load and not show by default, is there any way to fix that? Also, I'd like this to work without having to use javascript, if possible.

Comment: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: @Timmerz why don't you post your link as an answer? If you summarise "Test Seven" or "Test Five" it would be a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most browsers will download images even if you have them hidden.

There is no way to stop image load with just html and css alone. JS is the best way to do this and it is also very easy, so you might not have any choice but to use javascript.

Just incase you decide to  use javascript you should check out lazyload, it is very simple to use.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 0):

`"Adaptive Images"` detects the user's screen size and automatically generate cache for that particular size.
I have used this previously in some of my projects, it works like a charm.

You can find more information [**here**](http://adaptive-images.com/details.htm) and [**here**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/)

And you can't avoid Javascript, that's the only solution as per my knowledge. But it is easy, all steps are given in above links.